# How to access my domain only via a certain referer/website

Tags: javascript, php, .htaccess

How do i make my website accessible via a certain website or referer from that website only?

Say for example i only want my website to be accessible through adf.ly, how would i do such thing? Thanks for your help.

Note- adf.ly was just an example, i mean the general code.

Comment: Note; I meant how do i make it ONLY_ accesible through these sites.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use this in your /root/.htaccess  :

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} !adf\.ly
RewriteRule ^ - [F]
```

This returns a forbidden 403 status to clients if their referer doesnt match the pattern or it's not **adf.ly**

Comment: Thanks. Will try that and see how it goes. Is there any way to detect http spoofing?

Answer (score 0):

The simplest option is to check PHP's $_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER'] variable and deny any that does not come from your desired websites. But this is not a reliable method, as anyone can tamper with the HTTP request headers, setting the $_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER'] variable to false values.

If your request is not through a public client like a browser (for eg. you want to access via a server to server request), then you can rely on some sort of authentication to identify where the requests are coming from.